# Keep activity while the app is not on top of screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, exoplayer

I got a problem with multitasking, its probably a stupid question but after looking for hours an answer, i dont know how to do it everybody seems got that by default.

So my problem is I've two activities A (main) and B (conataing exoplayer), 
A--->B 
but when im on B and i press lock button or switch app: onPause is been called (normal) and onStop too, i reopen the app, and I'm back to A, the instance of B seem destroyed but the player still playing the audio.

What i would like to do is Keep B how it was or pause the audio/video on hold B, most important thing is to keep b on top and not go back to main (A).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start your activity B with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will start ActivityB as a new task and destroy ActivityA, so returning to it should not be possible. If you currently have some flags added to either ActivityA or B, they could also be interferencing with returning to desired activity after pressing home button.

Comment: Thanks very much it works ! Only problem the audio as an echo like if the player was playing two times or two instance of it, any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with exoplayer, but you might try to override onPause() method and inside it pause currently playing audio, then resume it in onResume()

Comment: Thanks i already override onpause with resume method of exoplayer but this put in on pause until the app is open again. And it replay automatically, but i would like never stop it, so I'm gonna keep looking to found a way how to do it. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the AndroidManifest you can use “launchMode” attribute inside the  element to declare the activity B's launch mode

```
<activity android:launchMode=”singleTask” />
```